# How to dynamically load content into DIV using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a website which consists of 5 different pages.

To maintain the design of all the pages, I copied and pasted the code from the main page to all the other HTML documents to make sure that the Navigation Box and the main divs stay in position.

I've now been asked to implement the design in such a way where when I press a button, the other HTML pages will load dynamically onto my main index page. This way, if I need to change the design of the pages, I only have to change the index page and not have to repeat those changes for every single HTML document I have.

I've tried using Javascript for this, but I can't think of anything that would suffice. I can't understand jQuery at all, if someone has a clear understanding of how to accomplish this task using jQuery or Javascript, could you please explain it to me step by step?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

<link rel="stylesheet"
type="text/css"
href="CSS/Index.css">

</head>
<script src="websitescript.js"> </script>
<body>
<div class="mainwrapper">
<div class="navbox"> 
<input type="image" id='about' src='images/about.jpg' 
onclick="myFunction()"> </a> 
<a href="location.html"> <img src='images/location.jpg' class="location"> 
</a> 
<input type="image" id='contact' src='images/contact.jpg' 
onclick="myFunction()"> </a> 

<a href="inquiries.html"> <img src='images/inquiries.jpg' class="inquiries"> 
</a>

<a href="employees.html"> <img src="images/employees.jpg" class="employees"> 
</a>

</div>

<img src="images/duo.jpg" class='logo'>

<div id="header"> 

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please share the relevant contents of websitescript.js?

Comment: Yes of course, give me a second please.

Comment: OK, added it at the bottom

Comment: Are you trying to load another page inside this page or some data.?

Comment: Another Page inside that page. The page I'm trying to load it into has a div which I want to load the content from another page into.

Comment: Here you have an answer with workin example https://stackoverflow.com/a/45030819/2765745

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you wanna do, is load content using [AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started) (XmlHttpRequest). That means, you have just one page with layout, and content/other pages are loaded without the need of reloading the page.

For that, you can use jQuerys [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) function. Tl;dr; what you gonna do, is to have content of the website as simple html files, without layout (header etc), and using ajax you are gonna load it into the page.

Content of your main page `index.html` could look like this (I removed those images in nav bar)

```html
<div class="mainwrapper">
  <div class="navbox" id="js-navigation">
    <a href="./about.html">About</a>
    <a href="./location.html">Location</a>
    <a href="./contact.html">Contact</a>
    <a href="./inquiries.html">Inquiries</a>
    <a href="./employees.html">Employees</a>
  </div>

  <div id="header"></div>

  <div id="js-content">
    <!-- content will be loaded here -->
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#js-content').load('/about.html');

    $('#js-navigation a').click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $("#js-content").load(e.target.href);
    })
  });
</script>
```

So in the same folder, you will have those other content files, but without navigation, wrappings header etc. Just plain content like:

```
<h1>About page</h1>
<p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
```

Comment: here you can download this working example. You just need to run in on a server (cant be used as `file://...` by simply opening file in browser, as ajax wont work on local files
https://www.dropbox.com/s/3nm0vxznlcc1yq4/test.zip?dl=0

Comment: Great Example, thanks!!; I have a question though, where does the AJAX come in? ...Where is AJAX being used? Thanks again.

Comment: @user1724708 it is use, when user clicks on link, seen i method  $('#js-navigation a').click(). Inside the click handler, i am calling .load() to handle links url, that points to page we want to fetch.

Answer (score -1):

Alright so my approach is a bit different as I use PHP but hopefully I am still able to help you with this. I am working on something similar where I have "index" page that includes a nav bar at the top and empty space below it. After I click on something the content of another php file loads into white space, and said another php file is wrapped into a div I can edit with css. To do this I've used this php command:

```
<div>
<?php
$page = "MainPanel.php"; // my index
    if (isset($_GET["page"])) {
        $page = $_GET["page"];
    }
    if ($page == "" or $page == "MainPanel.php") {
        $page = "/Main/central.php"; //default page upon running the code.
    }
    $GLOBALS["page"] = $page;

ob_start();
include($page);
ob_end_flush();
?>
</div>
```

This should be it. I don't know php very well and one of my collegues suggested to use this but it's relatively small amount of code and it works well.

Comment: He is using just JS, so maybe this is not an option, let's see what he says

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'm not really sure how to work with PHP. Do I have to create a PHP file which has the same attributes as my other page or do I rename my HTML document?

Comment: I might have to stick with the Javascript and Jquery solutions for this particular problem. But if I learn PHP anytime soon and my problem isn't solved yet, I'll definitely try this out.

Comment: Regarding your question I'm not really sure. I mean all my files are in php as you see in the code, You can use HTML, CSS, JS normally in those files but you need a server in order to run the PHP file with an index page (or xampp).

Comment: I see. Thank you for your help.